# Invalid use of group function Error in MariaDB - Update Query and SUM

Tags: sql, reactjs, mariadb

So im trying to write an update query that either updates the funds of a user based on if they have visa or MasterCard. 
What im trying to state here, and which im thinking is what causes the error, is to update the sum if the current balance and wanted withdraw amount is less than 10.000. If that is not the case and the visa balance becomes less than 0, im creating an intentional error so that i can use it later to redirect the user to an error page (i know its not the most PC way to do it).
This is how the code looks:

```
const connection = require('../models/loginrouters');

function takeMoney(amount, cardnumber) {
  // prettier-ignore
  console.log("db cardnumber is".cardnumber)
  console.log('db amount is', amount);
  connection.query(
    "UPDATE users.usercards SET Balance = CASE WHEN type = 'visa' AND balance>'" +
      amount +
      "' THEN Balance - '" +
      amount +
      "' ELSE CASE WHEN type='mastercard' AND SUM(balance - '" +
      amount +
      "')<'-10000' THEN Balance - '" +
      amount +
      "' ELSE 'NEIN CASH' END END WHERE CardNumber = '" +
      cardnumber +
      "';",
    function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('You too poor');
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('You got the cash');
      }
    }
  );
}

module.exports = takeMoney;
```

When this query is run I get the following error:
Error: ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE: Invalid use of group function

The query is posted to me as:

```
sql: 'UPDATE users.usercards SET Balance =
         CASE WHEN type = \'visa\' AND balance>\'1000\'
                  THEN Balance - \'1000\'
              ELSE
              CASE WHEN type=\'mastercard\' AND SUM(balance - \'1000\')<\'-10000\'
                      THEN Balance - \'1000\'
                  ELSE \'NEIN CASH\'
              END
          END
      WHERE CardNumber = \'123456\';'
```

In advance, thanks for your response!

Comment: You cannot use `SUM()` in an update, so the error message is correct.  What you actually want to accomplish is not clear.  Sample data (as a text table) and desired results would really help.

Comment: Thanks, that is all I needed to know. Sorry about the poor wording!
Ill try again to see if you might have a better sollution:
I basicly want to check if the users funds after the transaction will be less than 10.000. You see it as a credit roof / top on all mastercards. Is there then any way to check if the sum of current funds minus wanted withdraw amount will be less than 10.000?

Comment: @KristianMunter you will need compute the SUM in a derived table. Please add some relevant table structure and sample data

Answer (score 0):

So as Gordon Linoff stated in a comment, I cannot use SUM in an update query. I just wrapped it in a () and it works perfectly. 
TLDR; DONT use SUM in an update query.

```
  connection.query(
    "UPDATE users.usercards SET Balance = CASE WHEN type = 'visa' AND balance>'" +
      amount +
      "' THEN Balance - '" +
      amount +
      "' ELSE CASE WHEN type='mastercard' AND (balance - '" +
      amount +
      "')>'-10000' THEN Balance - '" +
      amount +
      "' ELSE 'NEIN CASH' END END WHERE CardNumber = '" +
      cardnumber +
      "';",
    function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('You too poor');
      } else {
        console.log('You got the cash');
      }
    }
  );
}
```